# Somewhat simple automapper nested property issue

Tags: automapper

I have a many to many relationship in my application and I'm using Entity code first so it looks like this (there is obviously more to it, but this is the basic structure):

```
Class Ingredient{
    int Id {get; set;}
    string Label {get; set;}
}

Class RecipeIngredient{
    Ingredient Ing {get; set;}
    Recipe Rec {get; set;}
    int Quantity {get; set;}
}

class Recipe{
    int Id {get; set;}
    List<RecipeIngredient> RecIngs {get; set;}
}
```

How do I handle the mapping to map this to the following DTO:

```
class RecipeDTO{
    List<IngredientDTO> Ingredients;
}

class IngredientDTO{
    int Id {get; set;}
    string Label {get; set;}
    int Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

Given that I already have the standard mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Recipe, RecipeDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDTO>();
```

I assume I have to do some Mapper.CreateMap().ForMember() stuff, but I have no idea beyond that.

Edit:  I added a couple properties to the RecipeIngredient class to make it more real world.

Comment: Does the class IngredientDTO have any properties? It would help if you post the complete class definitions as this can influence how you map.

Comment: It has a Id, Label, quantity, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RecipeIngredient, IngredientDTO>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Label, rc => rc.MapFrom(x => x.Ing.Label))
```

You have to do this for every property of Ingredient that maps to a property on IngredientDTO.